# Vimeo API: get a list of links for downloading all video files

Tags: python, python-2.7, vimeo, vimeo-api

Good day.

I'm trying to get a list of all video files (links to direct downloading) from Vimeo account.

Is there a way to do it in a 1 GET request? OK, times to 100, if it is restriction of API.

I had hardcoded script, where I am making 12 GET request (1100+ videos, according to documentation, request is limited by 100 results), and then  making over 1 000 requests to receive direct links.

**Is there a way to to receive a list of links for downloading videous from Vimeo with one API request to server?**

PS Account is PRO

```py
import vimeo
import json
import config #token is here

client = vimeo.VimeoClient(
    token = config.token
)
per_page = 100
answerDataAll = []
for i in range(12):
    page=i+1
    getString = 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?per_page='+str(per_page) + '&page=' + str(page)
    dataFromServer = client.get(getString).json()['data']
    answerDataAll.extend(dataFromServer)    

# creating list of videos
listOfItems = []
for item in answerDataAll:
    listOfItems.append( item ['uri'])

# creating list of direct links, it is the goal
listOfUrls = []

for item in listOfItems:
    # isolating digits
    videoID = ""
    for sign in item:
        if sign.isdigit():
            videoID = videoID + sign 

    requestForDownloading = client.get ('http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoID + '/config').json()['request']['files']['progressive']
    for itm in requestForDownloading:
        if itm['width']==640:
            urlForDownloading = itm['url']
            listOfUrls.append(urlForDownloading)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get up to 100 videos per request, but understand that a request like that to /me/videos will return the full metadata for each video, which is a lot of data to parse through. The API or your client may also timeout while Vimeo's servers try to render your request.

You should use the fields parameter so that only the download metadata you need is returned. You should also specify the sort and direction, so you know exactly order the videos should be returning in. The request uri should be formatted like this:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?fields=uri,name,download&page=1&per_page=100&sort=date&direction=desc
```

Documentation of those parameters is found here:

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#using-the-pagination-parameter

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#using-the-sort-parameters

Comment: To get download links, you'll need a PRO account (as you noted) or higher account level, and you'll need to authenticate your API requests as that primary account holder -- Team members cannot get download links for a primary account.

Comment: OMG! I got your idea! Tommy, if I had received answer without field "download", does it means, that my token is a token for "Team members"?

Comment: Does that token have the "video_files" scope?

Comment: I cannot check does it has  "video_files" scope (I'm not owner of accounts - just working with given token). And I do have a token for other PRO account, and it is returning item 'download', so your solution gaves me the answer on my question.

Comment: Tommy Penner, is it possible to get an available scopes for given token? (I had tried `/me`, but it is not describing right that my token has).

Comment: @ViktorIlyenko Make a request to /oauth/verify to get information about that token. Docs here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/authentication-extras#verify_token

Comment: Tommy, for the very first token I had received answer `'scope': u'public private'`, for my second (from other account) I had received "more powerful" answer: `'scope': 'public private video_files'`. Thank you very much for your help! You are really cool!

Comment: Great! Happy to help you out!