# How can I retrieve the URL of a video I have just uploaded?

Tags: python, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a Python script that pushes a video file to our Vimeo page via the api, which works perfectly. I'm just having trouble retrieving the link for the video we just uploaded. I found a snippet in the example documentation but it doesnt seem to work.

```
import vimeo
import sys

client = vimeo.VimeoClient(
  token="xxxxx",
  key="xxxxx",
  secret="xxxxx"
)

# Make the request to the server for the "/me" endpoint.
about_me = client.get("/me")

# Make sure we got back a successful response.
assert about_me.status_code == 200

# Load the body"s JSON data. WORKS UP TO THIS LINE ENABLE BELOW
print (about_me.json())
#sys.exit(0)

# Path to upload file
path_to_file = r"C:\Users\mydocs\Documents\SS19xGEN.mp4"

print('Uploading: %s' % path_to_file)

# Push file with credentials
client.upload(path_to_file, data={'name': 'TEST', 'description': 'test'})

# Return the uri
print("The uri for the video is %s" % (client))

video_data = client.get(client + 'fields=link').json()
print(('"%s" has been uploaded to %s' % (path_to_file, video_data['link'])))
```

The script works well up until the last two lines, which is my attempt at retrieving the URL of the video I just uploaded in the script, but that gives me the error = "Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'VimeoClient' and 'str'"

I have poured through the documentation and can't find any examples of how to do this, apologies for the beginner question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py), the `upload` method should return the uri:

```
# Push file with credentials
video_uri = client.upload(path_to_file, data={'name': 'TEST', 'description': 'test'})

# Return the uri
print("The uri for the video is %s" % (video_uri))
```

Comment: Any idea how I would instead get the embed code? IE "https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxx"  instead of - https://vimeo.com/xxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to receive list of videos using parameters `sort` and `per_page=1`

```
video_data = client.get('https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?sort=date&per_page=1').json()
```

Add `fields` you need in the end of url

Comment: Any idea how I would instead get the embed code? IE "player.vimeo.com/video/xxxx" instead of - vimeo.com/xxxxx

Comment: 1) "seriaalize" digits from uri (lets call it  `videoID` (please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118069/vimeo-api-get-a-list-of-links-for-downloading-all-video-files/56297096 , block `# isolating digits` )  2) concatinate it with part of target url: `url = 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + str (videoID)`